# you are using old version of this app, which no longer support account linking. please upgrade your app to continue adding device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

[image]

when I run the google home app add a device after when I click my app gives me error shown in picture

Comment: What kind of device are you adding?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the latest version of the Google Home app

Comment: sir, I install the newest one but gives the same error

Comment: @Dildarmuhammad There are three apps you should make sure are up to date: Google Home, Google Assistant, and Google (Search). The account linking flow you are using isn't implemented inside the Home app.

Answer (score 0):

Updating all 3 apps will do the job i.e. Google Home, Google Assistant and Google (search)
This is mentioned in comment of above answer.